# How to jump at a specific page in pageViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7

I am using pageviewcontroller in my app and I am retrieving images from db in app delegate class so that the images loads for once.
The problem I am facing is that I want to point at specific image in that array but it points to the first image.

Comment: Could u provide a screen shot of how your showing images in pageViewController and also coding parts too. That way your query will be more clearer to understand.

Comment: images are loaded in app delegate and theres a categoryViewController which is using tableviewcontroller.After tapping on index it open pageviewcontroller but the problem is ,if i tapped on second category ,it shows all the images,but I want to show from that category index to last index.

Comment: This will work fine in case when I am using tableview.What to do when I am using pageViewController in order to display images?

Comment: Share your code here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code because that you have mentioned you want to show from that category index to last index.Here pagetiles and pageimages are array

```
- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
NSUInteger index = ((PageContentViewController*) viewController).pageIndex;
if (index == NSNotFound) {
    return nil;
}
index++;
if (index == [self.pageTitles count]) {
    return nil;
}
return [self viewControllerAtIndex:index];
}

- (PageContentViewController *)viewControllerAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
if (([self.pageTitles count] == 0) || (index >= [self.pageTitles count])) {
    return nil;
}
// Create a new view controller and pass suitable data.
PageContentViewController *pageContentViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PageContentViewController"];
pageContentViewController.imageFile = self.pageImages[index];
pageContentViewController.titleText = self.pageTitles[index];
pageContentViewController.pageIndex = index;
return pageContentViewController;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So as you have your array of images(namely imageArray) then you could check out below code,

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  //As user taps on row of tableview then this method gets called so you will get the tapped row.
  NSLog(@"%d",indexPath.row);

  //With below you will get that image form your array using the row user has tapped.
  UIImage *image = [imageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

  //Now you pass that image to ur pageViewController and show it to ur user.
}
```

As I understood your query this might be ur solution. If anything else then let me know.

Comment: This will work fine in case when I am using tableview.What to do when I am using pageViewController in order to display images?

Comment: But you mentioned that you have a tableview controller in your comments. So let's not continue onto it ,firstly please update your post with your query and coding part. Then I will get idea of what exactly you require